# angular set error to form control and make it invalid in form group custom validator without the use of setErrors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Can someone help me how to set the minTemperature error to temperature form control in this from group custom validator ? so when i type less then 26 when Celsius is selected it should be invalid and have the minTemperature error and the same when fahrenheit is selected and is less than 80.

custom validator

```
  getTemperatureAndUnitValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (form: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } => {
      const temperatureControl = form.controls['temperature'];
      const selectedTemperatureControl = form.controls['temperatureUnit'];
      const temperature = temperatureControl.value;

      if (selectedTemperatureControl.value.code === 'F' && temperature < 80) {
        return { minTemperature: true };
      } else if (
        selectedTemperatureControl.value.code === 'C' &&
        temperature < 26
      ) {
        return { minTemperature: true };
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

form group

```
 this.heatIndexForm = new FormGroup(
      {
        temperature: new FormControl(null, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern(/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/),
        ]),
        humidity: new FormControl(null, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.min(0),
          Validators.max(100),
          Validators.pattern(/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/),
        ]),
        temperatureUnit: new FormControl(new Temperature('Celsius', 'C')),
      },
      { validators: this.heatIndexService.getTemperatureAndUnitValidator() }
    );
```

validation error in html

```
 <div class="validation-error"
            *ngIf="temperatureUnit.value.code === 'F' &&
            heatIndexForm.get('temperature').hasError('minTemperature') &&
            heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].dirty &&
            heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].value">
            Temperature must be 80&deg;F or higher!
          </div>
  <div class="validation-error"
            *ngIf="temperatureUnit.value.code === 'C' &&
            heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].hasError('minTemperature') &&
            heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].dirty &&
            heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].value">
            Temperature must be 26&deg;C or higher!
          </div>
```

i tried this in custom validator and its not working : (not triggering the validation error in template also the input is not applying red border, i am using pInputText and it has built in red border which is applied when input is invalid)

```
return {temperatureControl: { minTemperature: true }}
```

i dont want to use .setErrors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom error it's about the formGroup, so you should use

```
<div class="validation-error" *ngIf="heatIndexForm.errors?.minTemperature">
   {{heatIndexForm.value.selectedTemperatureControl.code=='F'?
                'Temperature must be 80&deg;F or higher!':
                'Temperature must be 26&deg;C or higher!'}}
</div>
```

To add class to the input

```
<input [class.ng-invalid]="heatIndexForm.errors?.minTemperature &&
                           heatIndexForm.get('temperatureUnit').touched">
..
</input>
```

NOTE: you can in your validator function return a complex object, e.g.

```
{minTemperature:true,errorText:'Temperature must be 80&deg;F or higher!'}
//and 
{minTemperature:true,errorText:'Temperature must be 26&deg;C or higher!'}
```

To only show `{{heatIndexForm.errors?.errorText}}`

Comment: thanks a lot for suggestion will use some to shorten my code, what i am trying to do though is not use the [class.ng-invalid] or [ngClass] as i am using pInputText primeng component which has built in ng-invalid and ng-dirty classes which triggers when input is invalid or dirty so all i want to do is make the temperature formControl invalid with the custom validator instead of passing the error to formGroup and making the formGroup invalid i want to pass it to temperature formControl if that makes sense

Comment: If you're using primeng, simply add `[class.ng-invalid]="heatIndexForm.errors?.minTemperature"` this add the class "ng-invalid" to your input when the "heatIndexForm" has error -even if the FormControl has no error)